# java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make java.net.InetAddress() accessible

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Trying to run micro service with MongoDB. Get following exception when app starts. But Strange thing another micro service which is uses exactly same set up starts without any issue.

```
Java_Version: openjdk version "17.0.3"
Gradle_Version: Gradle 7.4

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name "** Class "defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MainApplication: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate'
while setting bean property 'mongoOperations';
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate'
defined in class path resource[org / springframework / boot / autoconfigure / data / mongo / MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate'
parameter 1;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingMongoConverter'
defined in class path resource[org / springframework / boot / autoconfigure / data / mongo / MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mappingMongoConverter'
parameter 1;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoMappingContext'
defined in class path resource[org / springframework / boot / autoconfigure / data / mongo / MongoDataConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make java.net.InetAddress() accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net"
to unnamed module @5c34d01b
```

Comment: Are you on most recent spring-boot version?

Comment: Yes we are using latest version of springboot.Strangely other app works which uses same verison of java,gradle and springboot.